# jQuery validation - check if two passwords are equal

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am having some problems here, I have simple bootstrap form for change password integrated to my design and I want to validate it with jQuery.

What I want is simple, check if both passwords are same, and if not, display some error message.

My HTML looks like:

```
   <div class="container">
        <div class="row vertical-center">
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <br>
        <form role="form" action="" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Meno (email)</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text" placeholder="my@email.com" disabled>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Staré heslo</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Vložťe vaše aktuálne heslo" name="password-old">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Nové heslo</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Vložťe vaše nové heslo" name="password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password_again">Again</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Vložťe znova vaše nové heslo" name="password_again">
          </div>                    
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Zmeniť heslo</button>
        </form>
        </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I am trying to add something like:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
// just for the demos, avoids form submit
jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
  debug: true,
  success: "valid"
});
$( "#myform" ).validate({
  rules: {
    password: "required",
    password_again: {
      equalTo: "#password"
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Same script work perfect for me on my other code, so it looks i am blind or I don't know where I making a mistake!

Guys can somebody of you without watching to my code for days look at this and tell me what I am doing wrong?

THANKS!!

Comment: use http://formvalidator.net/

Comment: where is your 'myform' in html?

Comment: Actualy formvalidator.net looks cool. But is there a way how can i edit that default answer from JS like: Password isn't strong enugh (i want to display translated version of it)

Comment: for `formvalidator.net` you can create an object with messages and pass it to language options ([docs](http://formvalidator.net/#localization)). before that please answer for `caslaner's` question.

Comment: You are using the same ID for different input fields which is a no no. In your code you are referencing an input with ID of "password" but none of your inputs have that ID. Take a look at the demo [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/equalTo-method/) and go from there.

Comment: Can you add id="myform" to your form tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/site-demos.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myform">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Meno (email)</label>
            <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text" placeholder="my@email.com" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Staré heslo</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Vložťe vaše aktuálne heslo" name="password-old">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Nové heslo</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Vložťe vaše nové heslo" name="password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password_again">Again</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_again" placeholder="Vložťe znova vaše nové heslo" name="password_again">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Zmeniť heslo</button>
    </form>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
                debug: true,
                success: "valid"
            });
            $("#myform").validate({
                rules: {
                    password: "required",
                    password_again: {
                        equalTo: "#password"
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```